# Stop Editing vs Save and Close

Tags: 2013, master-page, save, edit, close

When in EDIT PAGE mode in SP2013, how do I get the full complement of "Save & Close", "Save and Keep Editing", and "Stop Editing" to show up in my "Save and Close" drop down off the toolbar?  Currently I have only 'Stop Editing' which basically removes any chance of CANCELing all my changes.

Answer (score 0):

Does the "Save" button in the ribbon have a little triangle at the bottom, just under the text that says "Save"?  If so, you can click on this to get the different options.